# how to override or extend ESM module in node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, overriding, es6-modules

i want to add new function or override function into module in type esm.

But I do not know how ؟؟؟

in CommonJS Is as follows

add new function

```
// include the module that you like extend
var fs = require('fs');
 
// add a new function, printMessage(), to the module
fs.printMessage = function(str){
    console.log("Message from newly added function to the module");
    console.log(str);
}
 
// re-export the module for changes to take effect
module.exports = fs
 
// you may use the newly added function
fs.printMessage("Success");
```

override

```
// include the module whose functions are to be overridden
var fs = require('fs');
 
// delete the function you would like to override
delete fs['readFile'];
 
// add new functional with the same name as deleted function
fs.readFile = function(str){
    console.log("The functionality has been overridden.");
    console.log(str);
}
 
// re-export the module for changes to take effect
module.exports = fs
 
// you may use the newly overriden function
fs.readFile("sample.txt");
```

but in ESM i don't know ?

for example

test.mjs

```
const add = (a,b) => {
    return a+b;
}

const sub = (a,b) => {
     return a-b;
}

export {add,sub};
```

index.js

```
import * as m from './test.mjs';

now , how to add new function or override 'add' or 'sub' in test.mjs
```

Comment: `m.add = (a,b) => {return a * b}`

Comment: how to export to test.mjs ????

Comment: No, you don't want to do that. Not being able to overwrite or extend module exports is a *good* thing. Provide a *separate* module instead which exports `printMessage`, and explicitly use that.

Comment: Yes it is possible
But I want to do this  challenge

Comment: Does anyone know the answer?